# Basic Modal Add title

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal

Thanks to some help when a user clicks a hyperlink the game notes (I send using hyperlink) open and display in a basic modal.  Now I am trying to add a title to it to show game date.  I have tried a bunch of things but nothing is working.

My javascript

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// Load dialog on page load
//$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

// Load dialog on click

$(document).on('click','#basic-modal .basic',function (e) {

    $('#basic-modal-content') 
    .text($(this).data('mydata'))
    .modal();

    return false;
 });
});
```

Calling my modal

```
<div id="basic-modal-content">

    <p></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal ...

Check out example #2 on this page http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/index.html

The sample just uses a h3 inside the element that gets modal'd.

If you're using jQuery's modal dialog, your syntax is a little off. You would have to use something like:

```
$(document).on('click','#basic-modal .basic',function (e) {
  $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
    modal: true
  });
});
```

Comment: I am using SimpleModal Basic Modal Dialog by Eric Martin.  I tried implementing your suggestions but they don't seem to do the trick.